# Keeping image and div on same line

Tags: css

I am new to CSS and what I want to do is to have a class for each `<li> </li>`. Each row has an image to the left and a `div` next to the image. The way I have it set up now is:

My CSS:

```
.popular {
  max-width: 192px;
  max-height: 50px;
}

.popular img
{
  display: inline;
  max-width: 45px;
  max-height: 60px;
}

.popular div
{
  display: inline;
  max-width: 125px;
  max-height: 60px;
  margin-left: 65px;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<li class="popular ">
 <img src="http://adaptiveblue.img.s3.amazonaws.com/movies/source_code/duncan_jones/tiny">
  <div>
   <p> Source Code </p>
   <p> Crap </p>
  </div>
 </li>
```

But they're all on a different lines.

Comment: Huh. Most of the reviews i've seen have been pretty positive. You didn't like it?

Comment: It's just for testing dude...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this, http://jsfiddle.net/C5GMZ/ ?

EDIT: I've added the code as [Kazark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526841/keeping-image-and-div-on-same-line/5526883#comment20800963_5526883) requested.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        ul.popular {list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
        ul.popular li {height:60px;margin-bottom:5px;width:192px}
        ul.popular li img {float:left;height:60px;margin-right:5px;width:80px;}
        ul.popular li div {float:left;width:107px}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="popular">
        <li>
            <img src="http://adaptiveblue.img.s3.amazonaws.com/movies/source_code/duncan_jones/tiny" width="80" height="60" alt="">
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://adaptiveblue.img.s3.amazonaws.com/movies/source_code/duncan_jones/tiny" width="80" height="60" alt="">
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://adaptiveblue.img.s3.amazonaws.com/movies/source_code/duncan_jones/tiny" width="80" height="60" alt="">
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes sir! but I want to have a class associated with that, so can you change it?

Comment: Do you want a class associated with the whole UL element or one of the LI elements?

Comment: Something like that, http://jsfiddle.net/C5GMZ/1/ ? But if you will add the same class name to all of those LI elements, then it's better to add that class name only to UL element. So in that case, http://jsfiddle.net/C5GMZ/2/ would make more sense.

Comment: Oh sorry. I don't know how it happened but copying and pasting the links removed my username. Here are the links; http://jsfiddle.net/demods/C5GMZ/1 for your question and http://jsfiddle.net/demods/C5GMZ/2/ for my suggestion.

Comment: Can you add the code to your answer? That is an expected practice here.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your stylesheet:

```
display:inline
```

Also, only the `<li>` tag has the popular tag.
You can select the others with e.g.:

```
.popular div {
}
```

Comment: and it should be .popular img?

Comment: I think it only needs to be on the div; the img is already inline. I don't know what will happen to the `p`s, though. Thinking about it, does this need to use inline-block?